# Magento Nofrills Layouts progmatically not working Magento 1.8.1

Tags: magento

I am trying to get to grips with working with layouts and came across Alan Storm's book Nofrills Magento Layouts (Good Book).

I have gone through the examples right up to page 19 adding in a new class under the Advanced Block Functionality section.

I have created all the files and templates as per the examples but I am now getting an error and cannot seem to progress until it is fixed.

The block class looks like this:

```
<?php
class Nofrills_Booklayout_Block_Helloworld extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
public function _construct()
{
        $this->setTemplate('helloworld.phtml');
        return parent::_construct();    
}
}
?>
```

The IndexController class looks like this:

```
<?php
class Nofrills_Booklayout_IndexController  extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
public function indexAction()
{
    $block_1 = new Mage_Core_Block_Text();
    $block_1->setText('Original Text');

    $block_2 = new Mage_Core_Block_Text();
    $block_2->setText('The second sentence');

    $main_block = new Nofrills_Booklayout_Block_Helloworld();
    //$main_block->setTemplate('../helloworld.phtml');

    $main_block->setChild('the-first',$block_1);
    $main_block->setChild('the-second', $block_2);

    //$block_1->setText('Wait, I want this text instead!');
    echo $main_block->toHtml();

}

    public function helloblockAction()
{
    $block_1 = new Mage_Core_Block_Text();
    $block_1->setText('Original Text');

    $block_2 = new Mage_Core_Block_Text();
    $block_2->setText('The second sentence');

    $main_block = new Nofrills_Booklayout_Block_Helloworld();
    //$main_block->setTemplate('helloworld.phtml');

    $main_block->setChild('the-first',$block_1);
    $main_block->setChild('the-second', $block_2);

    echo $main_block->toHtml();

}
}
```

and the template looks like this:

```
<h1>hello world</h1>
<p>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('the-first'); ?>
</p><p>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('the-second'); ?>
</p>
```

However when i goto my url to call the page:

```
http://www.phmagento.com/nofrills_booklayout/index/index
http://www.phmagento.com/nofrills_booklayout/index/helloblock

I get this error which is totally confusing me:

Warning: include(C:\xampp\htdocs\phmagento\includes\src\Nofrills_Booklayout_Block_Helloworld.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in C:\xampp\htdocs\phmagento\includes\src\Varien_Autoload.php on line 93
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\phmagento\includes\src\Varien_Autoload.php(93): mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'include(C:\xamp...', 'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 93, Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\phmagento\includes\src\Varien_Autoload.php(93): Varien_Autoload::autoload()
#2 [internal function]: Varien_Autoload->autoload('Nofrills_Bookla...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\phmagento\app\code\local\Nofrills\Booklayout\controllers\IndexController.php(12): spl_autoload_call('Nofrills_Bookla...')
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\phmagento\includes\src\__default.php(13969): Nofrills_Booklayout_IndexController->indexAction()
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\phmagento\includes\src\__default.php(18331): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\phmagento\includes\src\__default.php(17865): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\phmagento\includes\src\__default.php(20465): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\phmagento\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\phmagento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#10 {main}
```

If anybody has any clues as to why I am getting this error or what I am doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks
Graham

Comment: Disable the compilation and recompile everything.

Comment: Thank you Marius for your response I understand now where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The autoloader is trying to load the `Nofrills_Booklayout_Block_Helloworld` class from `C:\xampp\htdocs\phmagento\includes\src\Nofrills_Booklayout_Block_Helloworld.php`. Are you sure that file exists? It should contain the block from your first code snippet.

Comment: OK so pasting the file and renaming it to that location has worked but I don't understand why the book makes reference to add the file to app/code/local/Nofrills/Booklayout/Block/Helloworld.php?  Any clues?

Comment: That's the right path for the block inside the module. Normally it'd be loaded from there if you had the module set up right, but it looks as though you have compilation mode turned on. The src path in the error should be populated when you run compiler.php - I recommend reading http://alanstorm.com/magento_compiler_path for more info.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, I have turned off complitation mode where Alan points to and yes it works like a charm.  Many thanks for your help.